# Use one style but not both together in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, mergeddictionaries

I'm preparing the 511 certification, and one of the question I didn't understand was this one :

`You are developing a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) application.`

Two styles, **Blue** and **green**, are used for *Border* objects. The two styles have the same values for the
*CornerRadiusand* *BrushThicknessproperties* and different values for the *Backgroundproperty*.

You need to define the *CornerRadiusand BrushThicknesssettings* in either the Blue or the Green style, but not both.
What should you do?

A)  Separate Blue and Green into two files.Put the base settings in Blue and use MergedDictionaries. Ensure that the Blue file is second in the list.

**B)    Put Blue and Green into the same file.Put the base setting in Blue and mark Blue as BasedOn Green.**

C)  Put Blue and Green into the same file.Put the base setting in Blue and mark Green as BasedOn Blue.

D)  Separate Blue and Green into two files.Put the base settings in blue and use MergedDictionaries. Ensure that the Green file is second in the list.

**The correct answer is B**

Can anyone explain to me why It's B and not C

Comment: Looks wrong to me. Basing on Green while putting the attributes in Blue will leave Green without the attributes. That said, I assume this is from a practice exam?

Comment: **C** is the correct answer on this one, not **B**. However, it ain't be best practice to do it this way.

Comment: If this is a question from the actual exam you are in violation of the agreement you signed when starting the exam.

Comment: It's not, this is a practice exam.

Comment: In that case ask your money back

Answer (score 1):

If we go with answer **B** (Blue is base, and based on Green):

```
<Style x:Key="Green" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Blue" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Green}">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="BrushThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

Here, the `Green` style *does not* inherit the `BorderThickness` and `CornerRadius` properties from the `Blue` style.

How about answer **C**? (Blue is base, and Green is based on Blue):

```
<Style x:Key="Blue" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="BrushThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Green" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Blue}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

Here, the `Green` style inherits the `BorderThickness` and `CornerRadius` properties from the `Blue` style.

Seems pretty clear to me that **C** is the correct answer, not **B**.